# Run time error Cannot find database dll in vb6

Tags: vb6

Hi all I have an software running on a machine where it was developed. Now i make a setup.exe and try to install it on other machine.

It was successfully installed without any error. All the function are running properly i.e. adding the records in the database fetching it in the dropdown but the problem occurred when I generate the report.

As soon as I click on to generate the report the error message comes saying that

```
Run time error'20532'
Cannot find Database DLL.
```

I have no idea why this is occurring it is running perfectly on the first system but why on the other system it is showing error.

I am using MS Access 97 as a database.

I check the dll's if there is some thing missing but not find anything. all the dlls are present in the system32 folder.

Now what can I do... any one have any idea please help me... 
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using crystal reports?

Comment: yes.. but I find the solution Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the crystal reports.

I just install the crystal report on the target machine and its done.